# Why is my catch exception code not working?

Tags: php, mysqli

I can connect the database and the PHP but if I intentionally mess up the database, it doesn't do the code for the catch. The catch is not working. It only displays the warning. I would also like to know how to get rid of that.

This is the warning I get:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'mytodsssssasdsdasdassdos' in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\projects\index.php on line 10

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
  
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'mytodsssssasdsdasdassdos'; //real DB name is mytodos


try {
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $password, $db);
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    die (var_dump('Unable to Connect to the Database.'));
} //echo 'Connected.';
```

Comment: @juergend The docs for mysqli are extremely bad and full of problems. Doing it like in the manual is a terrible way to do things in this case. Mysqli docs don't even show how to enable error reporting properly not to mention the whole `die` thing

Comment: `die (var_dump('Unable to Connect to the Database.'));` is NOt what you want to do with try..catch. Mysqli connect errors are no different from all other errors and hence do not merit for the dedicated handling code

Answer (score 4):

By default error reporting for mysqli is disabled. The only "error" you ever get is the warning when the connection can't be established. You can't catch warnings in PHP with try-catch. However, there is a very simple solution. Enable error reporting properly and you will be able to catch all mysqli errors.

```
try {
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $password, $db);
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    // Do something with the exception here and rethrow it.
    throw $e;
}
```

On the unrelated note, it doesn't look like you need to catch anything there. Just stick to the standard way of connecting without any catching:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $password, $db);
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```